# Stop CSS loader spinning if form validation error, django, javascript

Tags: javascript, django

How do I stop the loader spinner showing if the form submit fails and the user has to complete a missing form field. The spinner keeps spinning forever while the user enters the missing information.

My submit button in the form:

```
...
  <div class="control">
    <button type="submit" class="button" onclick="showDiv()">Submit
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My spinning loader below the form:

```
<span class="loader" id="loadingdisplay" style="display:none;"></span>
```

My javascript on click event to display spinning loader:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function showDiv() {
           document.getElementById('loadingdisplay').style.display = "block";
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Try setting "document.getElementById('loadingdisplay').style.display = "none"

Comment: That makes it not display the loader at all. I'm trying to make it so it displays when the user clicks. At the start it's set to "none" in the <span> element, then when user clicks it's set to "block" but then I want it to get set back to "none" if the success page doesn't load and instead the user get an error because they didn't fill in all fields of the form and remains on the page with the loader.

Comment: Are you validating fields before submitting the form? If you are validating in the front-end, you can have that "spinner display" code over there. As soon as the form fields are invalid, you can set back spinner to None. Could you please post your forms and validation related code

Comment: Thanks, was about to add the extra details however the other answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a listener on your form or your field that will hide your loader.

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myInputField");
x.addEventListener("focus", myFunctionHideDiv);


function myFunctionHideDiv() {
  document.getElementById('loadingdisplay').style.display = "None";
}
</script>
```

Ressources :

- [EventListener documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)
- [Event documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. Except I made it so the function was: .style.display = "none";. Also instead of the addEventListener, I used 'onfocus'='myFunctionHideDiv() in the field'.